# How can we make angular 2 multiselct dropdown options after selection as links

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How can we make angular 2 multiselct dropdown options after selection as links. After selection of dropdowns, particular selection in dropdown should behave as link.

I have used angular 2 multiselect.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the How to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Manage Data <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a  style="cursor:pointer" (click)="OnLink1()">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a style="cursor:pointer;" [routerLink]="['edit']" >Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a style="cursor:pointer;" (click) ="OnLink3()">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And create below directive:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding,HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen(eventData: Event){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

}
```